# I want to save my canvas drawing to a bitmap image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing

In this class I use the canvas to draw and I want to save it to a bitmap image on the device so it can be  looked at later. Also I am concerned about the location because I plan to open the images in a gallery view in the same application.

Here is the Drawing class:

```
public class Drawing extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private int moodColor, brushColor = Color.WHITE;
    Context context;

    public Drawing(Context context) {
        this( context, null);
        context = this.context;
        paints.add(paint);
        paths.add(path);
    }

    public void setMoodColor(int moodColor) {
        this.moodColor = moodColor;
        switch (moodColor)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.tense);
            Toast.makeText(context, brushColor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        case 2:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.nervous);
        }
        case 3:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.stressed);
        }
        case 4:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.upset);
        }
        case 5:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.alert);
        }
        case 6:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.excited);
        }
        case 7:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.elated);
        }
        case 8:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.happy);
        }
        case 9:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.sad);
        }
        case 10:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.depressed);
        }
        case 11:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.bored);
        }
        case 12:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.fatigued);
        }
        case 13:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.contented);
        }
        case 14:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.serene);
        }
        case 15:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.relaxed);
        }
        case 16:
        {
            brushColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.tibike.doodleme.R.color.calm);
        }
        default:
            brushColor = Color.BLACK;
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected " + brushColor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); 
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setColor(brushColor);
        path = new Path(); 
        paints.add(paint);
        paths.add(path);
    }



    public Drawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setColor(brushColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Click on 'Mood' to choose color", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX(); 
        float eventY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY); return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY); break;
            default:
                return false;
    }
    invalidate(); return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: you want to store in external storage?

Comment: @Miklosflame and your problem really is...?

Comment: @pskink I don't know exactly how to save it as a bitmap.  I forgot to mention that i am new to android and what I found couldn't implement it without crashing.

Comment: @Miklosflame where do you want to store the bitmap in external storage or internal phone memory?

Comment: @Raghunandan I have a nexus 7 so it would be internal storage.

Comment: @Miklosflame what do you want to save as a Bitmap?

Comment: @Miklosflame did you try the below does it work for you?

Comment: @Raghunandan First I have to fix some bugs that I encountered, than I will continue with this... I discovered that the function isn't Drawing well so I have to modify it. The explaining was helpful, it got things a bit clearer, and I found this useful link too :) http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store it in external storage

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then

```
DrawingView dv;
dv = new DrawingView(ActivityName.this);
dv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
save();
```

To save

```
public void save()
      {
       Bitmap bitmap = dv.getDrawingCache();    
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
                File file = new File(path+File.separator+"name"+".png");    
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try 
                {
                    if(!file.exists())

                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);

                    ostream.close();                            
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

      }
```

To store internal phone memory

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

```
DrawingView dv;
dv = new DrawingView(ActivityName.this);
dv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
save();
```

To save

```
    public void save()
    {
      Bitmap bitmap = dv.getDrawingCache();

        try 
            {

                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("name.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, fos);

                fos.close();                            
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  }
```